# determine the date of last Android update and How to Degrate the Android OS Version to Last version with Pros and Cons

Tags: android, operating-system, updates

One of Our Team memeber Updated  Device OS version to Android PIE(9) and I have to check, when it has been done. is there any way to check updated version DATE-TIME.

I would like to know that what will be Pros/Cons for Downgrade the version from Android OS PIE(9)

Comment: Would you do this programmatically by writing some code?

Comment: No i dnt want to write code for this i want to check it from my device thats it.Just unable to Find Last Updated Android OS Date and Time

Comment: Then it's off-topic for Stack Overflow. And unfortunately at least I don't have an answer.

Comment: Suppose we can get the Details from OS file or any way to Find it Programmatically